# Deserialize JSON object to C# object

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

Im trying to read some json data using RestSharp.

But im having some problems reading json objects.
I have this respons:

```
expand: "html",
self: "<url>/INCIDENT-447",   
key: "INCIDENT-447",
fields: {
  customfield_11414: {
  name: "Corrective Measures",
  type: "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textarea"
},
  summary: {
  name: "summary",
  type: "java.lang.String",
  value: "BLA BLA BLA"
},
```

I need to create a object with Property's summery and customfield_11414
But i only need the value of them. Not the entire JSON object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and `dynamic` keyword together

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(dynObj.fields.customfield_11414.name + " " + 
                  dynObj.fields.summary.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. One is to not try and deserialise everything, but rather just make the JSON available for LINQ/XPATH style searching. This is using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
var json = " ... "; // your json here
var o = JObject.Parse(json);
var summary = o["summary"];
var customfield_11414 = o.SelectToken("customfield_11414");
```

These return everything as `JToken`, which you could cast if needed, or further parse.