# How to deserialize my json into class?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, arrays

My Json String:

```
{"Result":[{"branch":"61","food":"Idli","food_photo":[255,216,255,22,....55,217],"preparation":"23","qty":"Pcs"}]}
```

My Quest:1)When i deserialize i got null **food_photo**  in my list.
2)How to deserialize this json string into class in c#?

Comment: How are you deserializing? What is the class definition? (Show us some code)

Comment: public class Food
{
    public int branch { get; set; }
  public string food { get; set; }
    public photo[] foo_photo { get; set; }
    public string preparation { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    
}
public class photo
{
    public byte[] food_photo { get; set; }
    
}
public class FooddtlResult
{
    public Food[] Result { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 0):

Look at lots of similar questions on stackoverflow:

[What is the simplest C# function to parse a JSON string into an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859753/what-is-simpliest-c-sharp-function-to-parse-json-string-into-object)

[Deserialize JSON object to C# object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136049/deserialize-json-object-to-c-sharp-object)